# Getting empty ident name (for <>) not allowed ONLY in programmatic powershell

Tags: java, git, powershell

I have a java program that uses the Powsershell library Tuupertunut/PowerShellLibJava to execute a view git commands. But when executing a `git am` command git complains about a missing ident name:

```
fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed
```

This error is very strange because:

1. The same command works in all terminals, cmd, powershell, git bash
   and so on without any issues
2. User name and email are set both globally and locally in git and this is like the suggested solution in most cases but maybe not this time
3. The git patch itself is well formatted because it has been directly produced by git format-patch

`git config --local  -l` returns the expected output with user.email and user.name set correctly. So this is not the issue here. I have executed the java program as administrator but this does not work either.

I don't understand why the same command works in the same powershell when executed manually instead of programmatically.

So what causes git to throw 'fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed' if everything is setup fine and the comamnds are well formatted. Here is one example

```
git --git-dir=c:/Path/to/project/.git format-patch -1 [sha value] --stdout | git am -3 --ignore-whitespace --ignore-space-change
```

Do you have any idea? Please help me.

Comment: What is the environment variable `HOME` set to when you see the problem?

Comment: This issue is about the Windows environment and there is no HOME variable in Windows. Why do you ask for this variable?

Comment: Because Git uses it to find where your home directory, and therefore where your `~/.gitconfig` is.  If it is not set properly, then your `.gitconfig` will probably not be read.